# GridView which item template is GridView too

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I have a GridView item template of it is GridView too, the parent GridView has only one row, but an unlimited number of columns.

The problem is that when you add an item in a nested GridView its width may increase, which in turn will increase the width of all columns of the parent GridView.

How to make sure that the width of the columns of the parent GridView not recalculated?

Comment: What's the child gridview containing? Is it like images you wouldn't care possibly being resized a little, or text that a font size difference could be negatively received in the design? I mean you could set a fixed width on the GridViewColumn of the parent, or maybe throw your nested GridView in a ViewBox so it adjusts to the size of the parent etc.

Comment: No i can't scale content. Contet of child gridview is some kind of tiles, so ColumnSpan would be a good aproach. But i cannot catch the event which is recalculate width of columns.